# Is it possible to prove $E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^k}{n-1}\right]=E[(x-E(x))^k]$?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Assume $x_i$ is a series of independent samples from a identical distribution , $1\leq i\leq n$ .

Define $\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is the estimated mean.

From the estimation of sample variance, it illustrated $E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2}{n-1}\right]=E[(x-E(x))^2]$.

Therefore, is it possible to prove that $E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^k}{n-1}\right]=E[(x-E(x))^k]$ for any $k\in N^+$ ?

Just want to ask if it is possible, and if yes, may I have the proof.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I'll use the conventional notation $\bar x:=\frac1n\sum x_i$ for the sample mean, instead of $\mu$, which is often the symbol used for $E(x)$.

The assertion
$$E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^k}{n-1}\right]=E[(x-E(x))^k]\tag1
$$
is true for $k=1$ and $k=2$, but that's all. For $k=3$ here is a counterexample with sample size $n=2$:

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be independently drawn from a distribution such that $E(x)=0$ but $E(x^3)\ne0$. (For example, you could let $x$ take value $2$ with probability $\frac13$, and value $-1$ with probability $\frac23$, but the detail doesn't matter.)

To evaluate (1) for $k=3$ with the given $x_1$, $x_2$, calculate $\Delta_1:= x_1-\bar x$ and $\Delta_2:=x_2-\bar x$ and find that $\Delta_1 + \Delta_2=0$. This means that $\sum_{i=1}^2(x_i-\bar x)^3 = (\Delta_1)^3 + (-\Delta_1)^3=0$, so the LHS of (1) equals zero. However, the RHS of (1) equals $E[(x-0)^3]=E(x^3)$,
which is nonzero by construction.

---

ADDED: A variant of assertion (1) is true when $k=3$:
$$
E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^3\right] =\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}nE[(x-E(x))^3].\tag2
$$
To prove this, wlog $E(x)=0$. Write $x_i-\bar x=\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}x_j$, where 
$$
c_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1-\frac1n&\text{if $i=j$}\\
-\frac1n&\text{if $i\ne j$}
\end{cases}.
$$
Expanding $(x_i-\bar x)^3=(\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}x_j)^3$ gives a linear combination of terms $x_{j_1}x_{j_2}x_{j_3}$, where the three indices $j_1, j_2,j_3$ are chosen from $1,\ldots, n$ with replacement. To compute $E(x_i-\bar x)^3$, we need consider only terms where these three indices are the *same*, since all other terms will have at least one index appearing exactly once and will therefore have zero expectation. So
$$
E(x_i-\bar x)^3=E\sum_{j=1}^n (c_{ij}x_j)^3=\left( \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}^3\right)E(x^3)
=\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)^3+(n-1)\left(-\frac1n\right)^3\right)E(x^3).\tag3
$$
Summing (3) over all $i$ and rearranging gives (2) for the case $E(x)=0$.

For $k>3$ the above approach gives a formula for $E\sum (x_i-\bar x)^k$; but note there will be additional terms involving second or higher central moments of $x$.

Comment: Hey, thank you. But what if the sample size $n>k$ , would the same results hold or, there is also a counter example??

Comment: @SHORESHEN In general the identity (1) is not valid for any given $n$, $k>2$. However, you can prove using the law of large numbers that as $n\to\infty$, the LHS of (1), before applying expectation, converges to the RHS of (1) almost surely for any fixed $k$.

Comment: The denominator should be $n-1=1$ ..... but I think the expectation is also zero...

Comment: @SHORESHEN Right, the sum is already zero even before applying expectation.

Comment: Calculated k=3 for 1 hour..... It does not follows....

Comment: I tried $n>k$ as my precondition and expended everything out...... suppose to be not making silly mistakes.......Hh

Comment: @SHORESHEN Please see my edit for a general formula for $k=3$.

Comment: And I think even if the $E(x)\ne0$ your equation holds

Comment: @SHORESHEN Yes, 'wlog' means 'without loss of generality'